# jQuery - Bootstrap Carousel Slid Event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to make a simple event handler on my Bootstrap Carousel sliding, and as a test for later if statements, I'm just alerting the current slide, but it keeps returning 0 (My first slide) even though it's sliding from 1 to 2, or 0 to 1 for example, it will always show 0.

```
 var slide = $('#myCarousel .active').index('#myCarousel .item');
   $("#myCarousel").carousel()
   $("#myCarousel").bind("slid", function(){
   alert(slide);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issue by adding in the HTML of the slider div's the following

data-slide-number="1"

Further detail shown here: http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/carousel-extended